# self join with aggregation

Tags: join, self

MS sql server

ideally it could merge three selections into one and return one data set.

the pseudo code is :

select this_line, this_trimSeq, this_paintSeq
from tableA
join tableB on tableA.id = tableB.id 
where control_key = '11'

select max(paintSeq) as maxPaintSeq
from tableA
join tableB on tableA.id = tableB.id 
join tableC on tableB.zone_name = tableC.zone_name 
where zone_no between 54 and 121
and line =this_line (the result from the first selection)
and paintSeq<=this_paintSeq (the result from the first selection)

select max(trimSeq) as MaxTrimSeq
from tableA
join tableB on tableA.id = tableB.id 
join tableC on tableB.zone_name = tableC.zone_name 
where zone_no between 92 and 141
and line =this_line (the result from the first selection)
and trimSeq<=this_trimSeq (the result from the first selection)

any tidy way to do this? if not use CTE. thanks

Comment: It's bit hard, at least for me, to understand the question as it's currently phrased. Could you please share your table's structure, some sample data and the result you're trying to get for this data?

Comment: basically I need to use the result from the first selection  as filter for  next two aggregation which differentiate at zone_no. I found just join 1st and 2nd selection is ok, but join the 3rd, it becomes a bit messy. can anyone help?